# Spring "remembe my" не работает на ajax

Tags: java, spring

Есть приложение на angular material при авторизации поставил "remembe my" и если долго в приложение не производить никаких действий, а потом отправить данные через POST ajax-ом, то будет ошибка, что не найдена страница 403, а если обновить страницу (F5), то авторизации не потребует и ajax post-ом отправится нормально. Как такое можно исправить или это может какая-либо настройка Spring Security?

Comment: 403 - FORBIDDED
посмотрите сколько живет ваш токен в куках

Comment: Точно про них то я и забыл подумать